# How to import packages in virtualenv in python shell

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to make a function to make periodical notifications to users , especially , ios mobile devices.

Specifically, I use 'Scheduled task' of pythonanywhere. (https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ScheduledTasks)

This is my script to send notifications.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4
import sys,os,django
sys.path.append("/home/lkm/Folder/project/")
sys.path.append("/home/lkm/Folder/project/app/myvenv/")
print(sys.path)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"
from push_notifications.models import APNSDevice, GCMDevice
device = APNSDevice.objects.all()
if device is None:
    print('No Device')
message = 'Home Fried Potatoes, Yo-nola Bar, Soup du Jour, More...'
device.send_message(message)
```

But at the line of **'from push_notifications.models import APNSDevice, GCMDevice'**
I'm getting an error :

> 'ImportError: No module named 'push_notifications'

***I think it's because of not importing virtualenv because push_notifications package is inside of packages of virtualenv, in mycase 'myvenv' directory.***

But even though I import 'myvenv' by 'ImportError: No module named 'push_notifications'.

It makes the same error, do you have the solution for this?

***UPDATE (First script , second error message)***

```
#!/home/lkm/folder/project/app/myvenv/bin/python
import sys,os,django
sys.path.append("/home/lkm/folder/project/application/myvenv/bin/../lib/python/site-packages")
print(sys.path)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"
from push_notifications.models import APNSDevice, GCMDevice
device = APNSDevice.objects.all()
if device is None:
    print('No Device')
message = 'Home Fried Potatoes, Yo-nola Bar, Soup du Jour, More...'
device.send_message(message)
```

> ['/home/lkm/folder/project/application', '/usr/lib/python3.4',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
>   '/home/lkm/folder/project/application/myvenv/bin/../lib/python/site-packages']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/lkm/folder/project/application/schedule.py", line 9, in
>   
>       from push_notifications.models import APNSDevice, GCMDevice ImportError: No module named 'push_notifications'

Comment: where is the `push_notifications` located exactly? and i think you need to use the `import` and `importerror` tags instead of `django` since this has nothing to do with django.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen As I said above, 'push_notifications' package is installed by pip install ~ after activating myvenv virtualenv.

Comment: you did not specify how you installed in the original post.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I don't know what you say... Post?

Comment: In your question, [see this](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbl9z0hs3LAhUimoMKHUuVAOgQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F79804%2Fwhats-stackexchange-ese-for-op&usg=AFQjCNFeJ_xBqmXTsEtl5U5ateGRxQruUA&sig2=nNpelQhDI2O9Mpy7Qx8nkg)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen OK, then what do you mean that I didn't specify how I installed?

Answer (score 2):

I would change the shebang to use the Python from your virtual environment.

```
#!/home/lkm/Folder/project/app/myvenv/bin/python
```

Then you shouldn't have to append the virtual env to the python path, and you can remove the following line.

```
sys.path.append("/home/lkm/Folder/project/app/myvenv/")
```

However, if you really want to manually add the virtual env directory to the Python path, then I think you want to include the site-packages directory instead:

```
sys.path.append("/home/lkm/Folder/project/app/myvenv/python3.4/site-packages")
```

Comment: Thank you for replying ! But I actually tried this before but nothing happened... Thanks

Comment: Wow , then I got another error message 'ImportError: No module named 'project'

Comment: Even though I saw the path of that project in sys.paht... it's disgusting

Comment: I'm not sure what 'but nothing happened' means. It's difficult to help because you haven't shown your project layout or the full traceback.

Comment: I didn't mean it sorry @Alasdair , I updated what I got.

Comment: The `sys.path.append()` line in your second example looks wrong. Why did you remove `sys.path.append("/home/lkm/Folder/project/")`?

Comment: I see `/home/lkm/Folder/project/application` but not home/lkm/Folder/project` in the output. I don't understand why you have `/home/lkm/folder/project/application/myvenv/bin/../lib/python/site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing the file?
I see you have:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4
```

which means that if you're executing the file with:

```
./file.py
```

it will be executed with the system interpreter.

You need to activate the environment:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
```

and execute the file with:

```
$ python file.py
```

FWIW, I think the cleanest solution though is to have a [setup.py script](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) for your project (`packages=` argument being the most important) and define an [entry point](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point), similar to:

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': ['my-script=my_package.my_module:main'],
}
```

Then you run `python setup.py develop` after activating the environment
and you would run the script simply as a command:

```
$ my-script
```

Comment: Oh, that is another question to me too! Yes but I think pythonanywhere just executes my script without sourcing activate... Yes you're right.